# D3js: Unable to set drag behaviour to chess pieces

Tags: d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop, drag, chess

**Problem Solved == use d3.drag() instead of d3.behaviour.drag() and use d3-drag.v1.min.js**

I have set up a SVG chess board with D3js using for loop to go through each row and each column. I used unicode for chess pieces so each chess pieces is a  svg element.

I am trying to drag chess pieces with drag behaviour of D3js but not possible.

All chess pieces have class "draggable". So I created the drag and attached it to all elements with class "draggable"

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function() { 
       var t = d3.select(this);
       return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
    })
    .on("dragstart", function() {
       d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); // silence other listeners
    })
    .on("drag", function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("x", d3.event.x)
        .attr("y", d3.event.y);
    });

 d3.selectAll(".draggable").call(drag);
```

My full code is here http://codepen.io/linhnt1516/pen/ZeGoNj?editors=0011

Also, I have tried to use the same drag function with  and  svg elements in other examples. Check out this code pen http://codepen.io/linhnt1516/pen/VpvobE?editors=0011 and drag the text and the box.

I have been looking through tons of drag examples of D3js but none of them works with the chess piece case.

Anyone has any solution or idea where things may go wrong here.

Comment: It is dragging. What's the exact problem?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado hey, thanks for asking. I have figured out the problems. So the code is updated. The drag behaviour is fine now. Btw, now I want to move the piece to a new place, when the piece is over a square, that square get a new highlighted border. So each square has an event triggered when a piece is moved over it. Any suggestion?? Thank you.

Comment: If you have a different problem, please post another question. Not everybody reads the comments.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer so the question is answered. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully understand the differences between D3 v4 and D3 v3 drag behaviour or what is the actual problem with behaviour.drag()

Before I used D3 v3 and set up

```
var drag = d3.behaviour.drag()
```

This doesn't work as described in the question.

However I found a support d3 script which is d3-drag.v1.min.js

```
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So when I added this one and set up

```
var drag = d3.drag()
```

The detailed code of drag is the same as above, just different initialization syntax. The drag functionality now works correctly. If anyone knows why .behaviour.drag() doesn't work and what is the actual differences between my old code and the new working one, please enlighten me.